# Swift 4 - \n not working. How can I make this to another line.

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

```
var welcomeText: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    textField.text = "Hello, are you \n Im doing good! "
    textField.textColor = .white
    return textField
}()
```

I can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITextField` can only display a single line. If you want multiple lines of editable text, you must use `UITextView` instead.